# Restart systemd service if no log produced in timeout

Tags: systemd, monitoring, systemd-journald

Is it possible to monitor systemd service (unit), if it produces logs, and if no log is produced in (lets say 5 minutes), restart the service?

Answer (score 0):

So you can put logic based on below scenarios:

[1] Check pid if exists, if not restart application.

[2] Check log if not produced for some time(check what threshold you want to put), restart service.

```
journalctl <your application binary>
```

[3] If your application support endpoints for health check, you can write on top of it.

Actually we need to identify difference between idle and not working while checking logs, So I think checking single thing is not enough.

Comment: Thank you, [1] is not feasible, as the app seems to be running, however it is hanged, if it doesn't produce any logs, [2] is what I'm talking about, but I'm looking for automated solution, not manually checking, manually restarting scenario, [3] it does not support, it's 3rd party closed-source, which lacks this. [2] is great indication of "not working", because it actively sends out heartbeat and logs that action in syslog, so there is no idle-state confusion.